# empty image field in formset not valid and shows no errors

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Why form not valid an empty image field... fall into a database empty records
if I do a print (formset.is_valid) it returns me true and creates 3 fields with empty image when the image field is empty and should instead give me an error.

views

```
def product_gallery_create_view(request, id):
    ProductGalleryFormset = formset_factory(FormCreateProductGallery, extra = 3)
    product = Product.objects.get(id = id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ProductGalleryFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset: #true why??
                if form.has_changed():
                    instance = form.save(commit = False)
                    instance.product = product
                    instance.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        formset = ProductGalleryFormset()

    context = {'formset':formset}
    return render(request, 'crud/product_gallery_create.html', context)
```

model

```
class ProductGallery(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'product_gallery')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='galleria/')
```

form

```
class FormCreateProductGallery(forms.Form):

    image = forms.ImageField(required = True)

    def clean_image(self): 
        image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")
        if not image: 
            raise forms.VaildationError("Image field is required !")
```

html

```
{% if formset.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ formset.errors }}
    </div>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="notifica" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}
        <div class="d-flex align-item-center justify-content-between">
            <div><small>img</small> {{ form.image }}</div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mt-4 mb-4">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="crea galleria" class="btn btn-info w-100">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have defined FileField() in the image attribute .
Try using this .

```
class ProductGallery(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'product_gallery')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='galleria/' , default = "some_default_image.png")
```

And also the image field can be empty . It only throws error when viewed directly via the link , it does not give an error on templates or forms .

What you can do is use django signals to check whether there is an image in the the saved instance or not . Or use validations in form to make the image required field .

```
class ProductGalleryFormset(forms.Form) : 
    image = forms.ImageField( required = True)
    
    ...
    
    def clean_image(self) : 
        image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")
        if not image : 
            raise forms.VaildationError("Image field is required !")
```

You are getting redirected without seeing the error is because you have not set the else statement for the  `if form.is_valid()` method .

Instead of using the above form which you are using use this one :

```
Why form not valid an empty image field... fall into a database empty records if I do a print (formset.is_valid) it returns me true and creates 3 fields with empty image when the image field is empty and should instead give me an error.

views

def product_gallery_create_view(request, id):
    ProductGalleryFormset = formset_factory(FormCreateProductGallery, extra = 3)
    product = Product.objects.get(id = id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ProductGalleryFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.has_changed():
                    instance = form.save(commit = False)
                    instance.product = product
                    instance.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else : 
            print(dict(formset.errors))
    else:
        formset = ProductGalleryFormset()

    context = {'formset':formset}
    return render(request, 'crud/product_gallery_create.html', context)
```

Comment: I have trial but it doesn't work, the error is not shown to me and it redirects me without saving anything. the form.is_valid () field gives it to me true despite not having inserted any image

Comment: This problem gives me alone with the use of the formset if instead I put the single form the error is shown to me

Comment: You are not seeing the error because you have not defined else statement for it . In the else statement . print(formset.errors) add this line. I have updated in the answer.

Comment: no, I don't see the error because the code if formset.is_valid (): gives me true and then enters there, that's the problem. It does not show me errors because the code does not understand that the images have not been inserted, what you told me about the else is correct but it will not work because it enters first so it will never execute that print

Comment: I have updated the code with your changes and I thank you for the hand you are giving me

Comment: Awesome man . Thats great.

Comment: yes I entered def clean_image (self): in the form but it doesn't work or in any case it doesn't recognize the error

Comment: sisi I do but I haven't solved the problem, I was thanking you for your help in general

Comment: what is the problem . What is still left there ? Tell the exact problem , what is happening ?

Comment: it's still the same I haven't solved it,
if the image is not inserted the view to the formset.is_valid () returns me true anyway so the error is not seen and I need that if the image is not there I get the {{formset.errors}}.
I used your code above but it doesn't work it keeps giving me the same problem

Comment: Aren't you using two different kinds of forms , these are different ? FormCreateProductGallery , ProductGalleryFormset .

Comment: ProductGalleryFormset server me to call the formset_factory while the real form which is the only one is FormCreateProductGallery, there are not two forms but only one